# mgo golang doesnt update empty array using $set

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

struct and method:

```
type Group struct {
    Id                          int64            `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    MediaFilterExceptionUserIds []int            `bson:"media_filter_exception_user_ids,omitempty"`
}

func (g *Group) Save() error {
    return DB.C("groups").UpdateId(g.Id, bson.M{"$set": &g})
}

func (g *Group) FindById() error {
    return DB.C("groups").FindId(g.Id).One(&g)
}
```

trying to set media_filter_exception_user_ids to an empty []int{} and it doesn't work:

```
group := Group{}
group.FindById(123)
group.MediaFilterExceptionUserIds = []int{}
group.Save()
```

It works when there's an item inside the slice, but empty slice is not set.

Comment: Most likely because you used the `,omitempty` option in the tag. Which means if you try to save an empty or `nil` slice, it will not be sent over. Remove the `omitempty` option, or if you do need that, you may use a pointer to slice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MediaFilterExceptionUserIds type should change from []int to *[]int,

```
type Group struct {
    Id                          int64             `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    MediaFilterExceptionUserIds *[]int            `bson:"media_filter_exception_user_ids,omitempty"`
}
```

and then

```
group.MediaFilterExceptionUserIds = &[]int{}
```

will set it to an empty array in mongodb